# Sorting NSDictionary from JSON for UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am having trouble trying to sort my NSDictionary in order, and it's been weeks and I still haven't figured it out, so I wish some one could give me a hand here...

NSDictionary data is from JSON and the data is already sorted from the server and it displayed in order in the JSON, but when it retrieved and converted to NSDicitionary, the order is all wrong...

This is the JSON

```
{ 
  "categories":{
   "unknownCategoryName":[
   { "key1":"value1",
     "key2":"value2"
   }],
   "unknownCategoryName1":[
   { "key1":"value1",
     "key2":"value2"
   }],
   "unknownCategoryName2":[
   { "key1":"value1",
     "key2":"value2"
   }],
   "unknownCategoryName3":[
   { "key1":"value1",
     "key2":"value2"
   }]
  }
 }
```

The category quantity and its name will not be known until the JSON is received, so this is what I am using to get the count and setting up the tableView and the section

```
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];

NSDictionary *all = [results objectForKey:@"categories"];
self.datasource = all;


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
   return [self.datasource count];
  }

 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   NSString *title = [[self.datasource allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
   return title;
 }
```

And what I want to do is to list out the section and the section title as the order in the JSON.... rather than a chaos display like

unknownCategory3
unknownCategory1
unknownCategory
unknownCategory2

The "unknownCategory" is Product Category name, they are not in alphabet order, without any number, and they are already sorted and display in order in the JSON...

So, it would be great if you guys could help.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keys are not ordered in NSDictionaries, so you have to sort the keys first before using them in your table view.  So, instead of using [self.datasource allKeys] to get your section titles, first create a sorted array: sorted = [[self.datasource allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)], and then use that array to get the titles: title = [sorted objectAtIndex:section].

After Edit to answer a further question:

To use the sorted array to get the values you want into your table, I think this should be close. You would have to add a property, NSArray *sorted, to your .h file, and then this in your .m (this is assuming the structure of your json is as you posted above):

```
 NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];
    NSDictionary *all = [results objectForKey:@"categories"];
    self.datasource = all;
    self.sorted = [[self.datasource allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return [self.sorted count];
    }

    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        NSString *title = [self.sorted objectAtIndex:section];
        return title;
    }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [[self.datasource valueForKey:[self.sorted objectAtIndex:section]]count];
   }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        NSArray *theArray = [self.datasource valueForKey:[self.sorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        NSString *text1 = [[theArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"key1"];
        NSString *text2 = [[theArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"key2"];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r%@",text1,text2];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0; // this set the number of lines to unlimited
        return cell;
    }
```

You didn't say how you wanted to display two different values in one table row -- in this example, I concatenated them into one string with a return between the two.

Comment: the section title values are not in alphabets order and they contains no number, so they cannot be compare... in fact they are listed in order within the JSON...

Comment: If they are strings you can sort them with compare. Are they not strings? It doesn't matter if they're sorted in the JSON, when you convert it to a dictionary it won't necessarily be in order any more.

Comment: yes, they are string... but they are in Japanese characters, so I am not sure how to sort them to get the same order as in the JSON file...

Comment: @SArumik -- Items in a JSON "object" (equivalent to an NSDictionary) are by [definition](http://www.json.org/) not ordered.  If they appear in order in the original JSON string that would be regarded as pure coincidence.

Comment: @rdelmar -- Thank you, yes, the sorted array did give me the sorted unknown key for the section. But I couldn't figure out how to get the content inside that is following the sorted key order...  will be great if you could show me some more... thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question -- do you want to display "value1" and "value2" in your table view? And if so, how do you want to display them -- would they be 2 separate rows in a section?

Comment: @rdelmar each unknown category will be in a separate section, so in the above JSON, there will be 4 sections. And each section will have only 1 row that display both the value 1 and value 2. 

With your sample, I could get the unknown key sorted, but I am still working on how to display the sorted key in tableView titleForHeaderInSection   and getting the data for that section in order.

Comment: @SArumik, I edited my answer to show you how to get the data into your table view

Comment: @SArumik, I edited again because I forgot to put in the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a strange JSON. You could have used like this

```
{
"categories": [
    "unknownCategoryName": [
        {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
        }
    ],
    "unknownCategoryName2": [
        {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
        }
    ]
]
}
```

And it is very easy to sort if you did like above.

**To sort JSON provided in your question**

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getAllKeys:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary{

       NSDictionary *all = [results objectForKey:@"categories"];
       NSMutableArray *allKeys = [all allKeys];
       NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
       NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: sorter]; 

       [allKeys sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]; 
       [sorter release];

       return allkeys;
   }

   -(void)createSortedDictionary{
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryMutable=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        for(NSString *string in allkeys){

           [dictionaryMutable setObject:[all objectForKey:string] forKey:string];
        }
     }
```

`dictionaryMutable` will hold the sorted dictionary

Comment: thanks, i could get the dictionaryMutable working and showing it in order in nslog, but how could i get the data inside that would display in order in each section?

Answer (score 0):

Did you write this JSON or are you getting it from somewhere that you can't edit? It looks malformed to me. categories should be an array and the current array placement makes no sense. If the JSON looked like this:

```
{ 
  categories:[
   {unknownCategoryName:
   { key1:value1,
     key2:value2
   }},
   {unknownCategoryName2:
   { key1:value1,
     key2:value2
   }}
  ]
 }
```

Then you could read categories into an NSArray, and your delegate methods would look like this (and display in proper order):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
      return [categoriesArray count];
  }

 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     NSDictionary *dict = [categoriesArray objectAtIndex:section];  
     NSString *title = [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];
     return title;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the JSON reminder. But it seems like  the order at NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];   is already messed up...  even if I convert "result" into an array, the order is still not as same as in the JSON...

Comment: You don't need to convert it into an array. You read it as an array and the order will stay the same. NSArray * categoriesArray = [results objectForKey:@"categories"];

Comment: An array structure in JSON will be read into NSArray in the same order as it appears in the JSON, so you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can preserve the original order is to do the initial parsing yourself after creating a JSON string from the JSON data. If the structure of the JSON string is as you posted, you could use an NSScanner to find the strings between quote marks, and then select only the ones that have a [ after the final quotation mark to add to an array which will be your ordered array of keys. You can then create the NSDictionary using a JSON parser, and get the values by looping through your ordered keys and sending them valueForKey:.