# parsing JSON response from server in same order in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

i have an app which fetches JSON response from server. the JSON response from server looks as follows:

```
{"status":"SUCCESS","message":"XYZ","token":"ABCDEFGHIJ"}
```

now i need to store this in a NSDictionary for further parsing. so i use the following approach:

```
    urldata1=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&res   error:nil]; NSDictionary
    *myDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urldata1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
 }
```

but now the dictionary i get looks as follows:

```
{
    message = "XYZ";
    status = SUCCESS;
    token = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
}
```

So i see that the dictionary has been sorted on the basis of keys... is there a way to reproduce the exact same response from server in my dictionary..

Comment: if u want to get order wise form server then from server side u have to change dictionary key/value pair as array of dictionaries....like that [{"key":"value"},{"key":"value'},..]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter in what order the `NSDictionary` is because you retrieve the object from the dictionary with keys. 
So if you want to access the status first use this code

```
NSString *status  = [myDictionary objectForKey@"status"];
NSString *message = [myDictionary objectForKey@"message"];
NSString *token = [myDictionary objectForKey@"token"];
```

And you can access a Dictionary inside a Dictionary like this

```
NSDictionary *dict= [myDictionary objectForKey@"SomeOtherDictionary"];
```

Comment: i know we retrieve it using keys but in my case i need to reproduce the dictionary in similar way as i am getting from server. because this dictionary contains a sub dictionary and i need the keys in same order as the received response from server.

Comment: @ArpitRaniwala can you please post the full code you receive from server?

Comment: {"status":"SUCCESS","message":"NA","users":{"171":{A Dictionary inside},"20":{A Dictionary inside},"110":{A Dictionary inside},"8":{A Dictionary inside},"16":{A Dictionary inside}},"totalCount":41}

But after applying JSON serialization the dictionary looks like follows:
{"status":"SUCCESS","message":"NA","users":{"110":{A Dictionary inside},"16":{A Dictionary inside},"171":{A Dictionary inside},"2":{A Dictionary inside},"8":{A Dictionary inside}},"totalCount":41}

Comment: i have posted the response... Will be waiting for ur reply.

Comment: +1. Dictionaries are unordered in their nature. I'm guessing you want to access the "users". Try something like [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"users"] allKeys]; to get an array of all the user IDs. From there you can sort the array, then use [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"users"] objectForKey:userID]; to get the dictionary for THAT user. How you want to sort that array is up to you of course.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a dictionary is meaningless. You need to first create an array which will sort according to your needs.

You can refer [Sorting NSDictionary from JSON for UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386100/sorting-nsdictionary-from-json-for-uitableview) for further explanations.