# How to set Dictionary value ascending order into UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I have below json. When I set into UITableview but json not set into ascending order

in my tableview header which set dictionary key ex. Level1,Level2,Level3

I want Level1,Level2,Level3 but i get Level2,Level1,Level3 in my tableview header

```
    {
            Level1 =         (
                            {
                    "value" = 10000;
                    "image" = “image01.png”;
                    "name" = Luck;
                    "id" = 11;
                }
            );
            “Level2” =         (
                            {
                    "image" = "image02.png";
                    "name" = "Invites 3";
                    "id" = 5;
                },
                            {
                    "image" = "image03.png";
                    "name" = "Best coin”;
                    "id" = 2;
                }
            );
            Level3 =         (
                            {
                    "value" = 1000;
                    "image" = "image04.png";
                    "name" = “get clock“;
                    "id" = 3;
                },
                            {
                    "value" = 1500;
                    "image" = "image05.png";
                   "name" = “slot”;
                    "id" = 4;
                },
                            {
                    "value" = 1500;
                    "image" = "image06.png";

                    "name" = “Friend List”;
                    "id" = 5;
                },
                            {
                    "value" = 2500;
                    "image" = "image07.png";

                    "name" = "Deals";
                    "id" = 7;
                },
                            {
                    "value" = 15000;
                    "image" = "image08.png";
                    "name" = “time all”;
                    "id" = 10;
                }, 
}
```

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386100/sorting-nsdictionary-from-json-for-uitableview?

Comment: NSArray *dictToSortKeys = [dictToSort.allKeys
    sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

Comment: please give me with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered by definition.

You could

- Get the "Level" keys (as array)
- Sort it.
- Get the values in order of the sorted keys.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: Don't use a dictionary as a data source for a table view, since dictionaries are inherently unordered.

The link @Jarmod provides shows you how to make this work by building a sorted array of keys, but the better answer is to refactor your data into an array of dictionaries.